# How to know an incoming sync packet is inteded for a particular vob

Tags: clearcase

How to know an incoming sync packet is inteded for a particular vob?

multitool lspacket -l  doesn't tell for which vob this is intended.

I have several incoming packets intended for my replica but when I import them using this command i am getting the below error:

`C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\var\shipping\ms_ship\incoming>multitool syncreplica -import sync_usal_unix_2012-11-29T23.00.17-05.00_2296`

multitool: Error: Sync. packet C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\var\shipping\ms_ship\incoming\sync_usal_unix_2012-11-29T23.00.17-05.00_2296 is not applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, [`multitool lspacket`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_ref.doc/topics/mt_lspacket.htm) is the right command to check initially:

The [OP vchitta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771245/vchitta) [initially thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643014/how-to-know-an-incoming-sync-packet-is-inteded-for-a-particular-vob/13643290#comment18759104_13643290):

> The `lspacket` gave the below out put which shows that the intended replica name is correct but it doesn't reveal the VOB details.

```
multitool lspacket sync_usal_unix_2012-12-01T23.01.06-05.00_19957 
Packet is: C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\var\shipping\ms_ship\incoming\sync_usal_unix_20‌​12-12-01T23.01.06-05.00_19957 
Packet type: Update Packet fragment: 1 of 1 
VOB family identifier is: 360ab8c4.661e11d3.a49e.00:01:80:a9:b5:ec
```

To which [I argued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643014/how-to-know-an-incoming-sync-packet-is-inteded-for-a-particular-vob/13643290#comment18760460_13643290):

> Did you search '`360ab8c4.661e11d3.a49e.00:01:80:a9:b5:ec`' in the vob registry?
>   (or simply `cleartool lsvob -l`)
>   Is there any other Vob which would have the same uid?
>   See [VOB objects and VOB replica objects](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/c_vob_repl_obj.htm).
>   Yes or no, this is your answer right there.

THE IBM documentation clearly mentions:

> Each replica is a VOB, but the VOB object and VOB-replica object are different objects in the VOB database.
>   Specifically:
>
> - **VOB object**: The database has a single VOB object.
>     This object’s UUID is listed as the **VOB family uuid** in a `lsvob –long` listing.
> - **VOB-replica object** (or replica object): The database has a VOB-replica object for each of the VOB’s replicas.
>     This object’s UUID is listed as the **Vob replica uuid** in a `lsvob –long` listing.

The OP [adds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643014/how-to-know-an-incoming-sync-packet-is-inteded-for-a-particular-vob/13643290#comment18761898_13643290):

> No.
>   No vob is having family identifier with the above UUID.
>   Now I am able to find which vob a packet is intended for with the help of family UUID.
>   I found this particular packet is for Platfom vob which I didn't replicated yet.

---

Original answer

See first "[Packet is not applicable to any local replicas](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/c_inapplicable_pckts.htm)"

> To verify that the host-name property of a VOB replica is wrong, enter the following command:

```
cleartool describe –fmt "%[replica_host]p\n"
replica:importing-replica-name@VOB-tag
```

> For example:

```
cleartool describe –fmt "%[replica_host]p\n" replica:newyork@/vobs/tests
manhattan
```

> If the host name is incorrect, use the `chreplica` command to change it. At the master replica of the importing replica, enter a `chreplica` command:

```
multitool chreplica –c "comment" –host new-host
 replica:importing-replica-name@VOB-tag
```

> For example:

```
multitool chreplica –c "change host name" –host brooklyn
replica:newyork@/vobs/tests
Updated replica information for "newyork".
```

> Send an update packet to the other replicas in the family.

---

You can have multiple causes, as describes in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122854)

> #### Cause
>
> - The import command may have been run from a host other than the VOB server.
> - The hostname associated with the replica may have changed and MultiSite has not been updated.
> - The VOB server may have multiple host names and or multiple network cards and MultiSite is not properly configured to work with them.
>
> #### Resolving the problem
>
> **For cause 1**:
>
> Make sure the `syncreplica -import` command is being run on the VOB server host.
>   The `syncreplica -import` command must be run on the VOB server host as it is a server operation.
>
> **For cause 2**:
>
> Check the hostnames associated with the replica and compare the outputs using the two commands below.
>   The VOB and the replica should show identical "`host`" output. If they do not, this is likely to be the problem.
>   Use the `multitool chreplica -host` command to resolve the problem.
>   Review the MultiSite Administrator's Guide on the topic of `chreplica` (`multitool man chreplica`) for more details.

```
    cleartool lsvob -long <vob tag>
    multitool lsreplica -long <replica-name>
```

> **For cause 3**:
>
> If the import is in fact being run on the correct server host, check to see how many hostnames that machine has.
>   Maybe the server has more then one network card, or several aliases.
>   If there is more than one name, make sure that the alternate_hostnames file exists.
>
> It should contain each and every hostname the machine has, one per line.

Note: The alternate_hostnames file is supported on UNIX® and Linux® only.

Comment: Cause 1:<br>I am running the syncreplica -import on VOB server host itself.

Comment: i don't find multiutil in my server software installation itself. Did i miss anything during installtion?

Comment: And `cleartool lsvob -long \IP` & `multitool lsreplica -long coe_hyd@\IP` both gave `Server host` same. And so Cause 2 is ruled out? My Server has only single host name in hosts file. Can you please suggest now what could be wrong here?

Comment: I don't event find multiutil executable in my server installation! What could be wrong?

Comment: @vchitta Sorry '`multiutil` is for ClearQuest. I have edited and updated the first part of this answer, to adapt it to ClearCase, not ClearQuest.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But the host name is correct. I tried `cleatool describe` command to get the hostname and it resulted correctly. Now, my requirement is, i have several packets in the incoming shipping bay folder and i don't know whether these packets are for anyof the vobs which are not still replicated in my replica. Fyi, i have created a new replica with name coe_hyd and i am replicated vobs one by one from greenville server. So till now i have replicated 4 vobs out of 20 vobs. So could it be that these incoming packets are for the remaining 16 vobs that i still to replicate?

Comment: Also, is there a way to view/know these incoming packets for which vob, they are intended? That is my original question is.

Comment: @vchitta "So could it be that these incoming packets are for the remaining 16 vobs that i still to replicate?": possible. Beside the `lspacket`, I don't know how to confirm which vob is concerned: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc%2Fc_manual_synch.htm. What exactly does return the `lspacket`? No "`VOB family identifier`"?

Comment: the lspacket gave the below out put which shows that the intended replica name is correct but it doesn't reveal the VOB details.                                                            multitool lspacket sync_usal_unix_2012-12-01T23.01.06-05.00_19957

Packet is: C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\var\shipping\ms_ship\incoming\sync_usal_unix_2012-12-01T23.01.06-05.00_19957
Packet type: Update
Packet fragment: 1 of 1
VOB family identifier is: 360ab8c4.661e11d3.a49e.00:01:80:a9:b5:ec
Comment supplied at packet creation is:
Packet intended for the following targets:
  coe_hyd

Comment: @vchitta did you search '`360ab8c4.661e11d3.a49e.00:01:80:a9:b5:ec`' in the vob registry? (or simply `cleartool lsvob -l`)? Is there any other vob which would have the same uid? (see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc%2Fc_vob_repl_obj.htm). Yes or no, this is your answer right there.

Comment: No. No vob is having family identifier with the above UUID. Now i am able to find which vob a packet is intended for with the help of family UUID. I found this particular packet is for `Platfom` vob which i didn't replicated yet. Thank you verymuch VonC. This answered my question.

Comment: @vchitta Excellent. I have edited my answer to make that procedure more visible.